# Final temperature of an isolated vessel - Thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-transfer

8) Consider an inextensible tank of 10 m3 of volume, isolated by an adiabatic 
wrap. The tank contains nitrogen at 2 bar and 300 K. This tank is connected to a piping by which more N2 (at 300 K) is added to the tank until the internal pressure reaches 8 bar. At this moment, the admission valve between the tank and the piping is closed.

What is the final system temperature?

(Resposta: T = 381,8 K)

---

I seriously can't seem to get this answer right. I can calculate the number of mols in the initial state, but how do I calculate the final number of N2 mols (and then the temperature)?

Also, I'm not that used to concept of adding a gas (at 300 K) to more gas at 300 K and the temperature increasing. Can you explain it to me?

Comment: So if the tank volume stays the same and the pressure increases, what happens to temperature? Why do diesel engines work on compression ratio...

Comment: I can't expand your comment, could you post it in the form of an answer?